# Why do I need a pullup resistor at the gate when using a pmos as a high side switch

Tags: pmos

Very quick question:

Assuming I am using a pmos as a high side switch and my supply voltage and the voltage at the gate I want to switch the transistor with (V_logic) are the same. I usually find something like this:
[image: pmos pullup]

Now I actually don't quite understand why I need the pullup here. Wouldn't the circuit work just fine without it as well?

Comment: Please add \$V_{OH}min\$ of the driving logic in terms of \$V_{CC}\$.

Comment: What's "usually" connected to V_logic?

Answer (score 1):

You need the pullup because otherwise you risk to have it open accidentally by having it floating. You normally can put even higher R value, like 100kR for keeping the FET blocked.
Idea is to have a resistor with a big value not to lose current when commanding it.
When you don't command it, you have it closed (blocked) by default because of that resistor.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what is driving the gate.

If it is a logic chip, it does not need a pull-up, because it has a push-pull output.

If it is a MCU, it needs a pull-up to keep the FET off, until someone has programmed the MCU with a program that configures the pin as push-pull output. It also may take milliseconds before MCU powers up and starts executing any code to configure the pin as push-pull output.

Answer (score 0):

The main function of that resistor is to make sure the PMOS is not in conduction when the V_logic is for example high impedance.

If V_logic is the an output pin of a microcontroller, it is probable that the after reset the pin is defualt configured as an input so the gate is floating. Imagine you are debugging and there is a breakpoint before setting the input as output or there is a firmware issue that keeps restarting the microcontroller. In this case, without the RGS (R_pu) the PMOS may be in condition and this can be a problem.

Comment: (`in condition` if not in blessed circumstances?)

Comment: I see. But if I can guarantee that V_logic is always stable logic high or low I technically wouldn't need it, would I?

Comment: Ask your self: What am I controlling? Do I care if the output is always ON if something happens? Because the controlling part can always fail (bad soldering, component burned, ...).